# Reloading a component but maintaining the same instance in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, instance

Let's say that I have a canvas component called myCanvas and I instantiated it with

```
var myCanvasPage:myCanvas = new myCanvas;
this.addChild(myCanvasPage);
```

Then I want to essentially reload myCanvasPage later on.  In effect I want to do this:

```
this.removeChild(myCanvasPage);
var myCanvasPage:myCanvas = new myCanvas;
this.addChild(myCanvasPage);
```

except instead of creating a new instance of myCanvas, I want to use the already created instance of myCanvas and essentially reload or re-create it but making sure that the instance name and references to it remain the same.  What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you do

```
var myCanvasPage:myCanvas = new myCanvas;
```

you are instantiating the myCanvasPage Object.
Removing an object from the stage will not delete the Object from memory.
As long as there is a reference somewhere in your code the myCanvasPage Object will not be garbage collected and all the values and attributes will be the same as at the time you removed it from the stage.
To make that reference you have to scope it to your class.

```
public var myCanvasPage:myCanvas = new myCanvas;
```

So now you would reference it with

```
this.myCanvasPage
```

and when you are ready to add it back to the stage.

```
this.addChild(this.myCanvasPage);
```

So to recap you can add and remove an Object from stage

```
this.addChild(this.myCanvasPage);
this.removeChild(this.myCanvasPage);
```

all day long and the data in that object will never go away.

[Some good reading on garbage collection](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/garbage_collection.html)

Comment: @The_asMan @sixfeetsix Ok, I think there is a misunderstanding. I understand that removing an object from the stage does not delete it from memory and instantiating a new myCanvas object creates a totally new and separate one. My example wasn't a good one because my basic question doesn't have anything to do with the stage. I basically wanted to know if I can take an already instantiated object and esentially re-instantiate it (force it to go through the creation life cycle again). Dunno if that makes sense.

Comment: If you mean like reusing the var yes the "new" operator will recreate the instance.

Comment: Just keep in might the scoping when you do this.

Comment: The "new" operator seems to create a whole new instance.  For example, the original instance name given by flex might be myCanvas325 but reusing the var with the "new" operator will create another instance such as myCanvas455

Comment: @Steven OK "I think" I understand Re-instantiating an object will give you basically a brand new object kind of like buying a new car. This is due to the new operator. In your case for whatever reason you do not want to go through re-instantiating the object you want to reinitialize it. This would be done with a public init function built into your class. In this function you will have the code that resets all your class properties back to a default level.

Comment: My question to you is why are you so focused on NOT re-instantiating the object. Is there some data you are trying to keep?

Comment: @The_asMan I'm using the object within a ViewStack and pass a reference to that specific object instance when changing to a different view in the ViewStack.  So for example, if changing to a different view, I will pass the object so that the user can go back to that object in the ViewStack if desired.  Now, I also want to re-initialize that object at times, but if I re-instantiate it, then the reference no longer applies.  I can reinitialize it through a function built into the class that will essentially reset it, but was wondering if there was another way.

Comment: If you scope it properly the reference will never go away. In a last ditch effort just scope it globally.

Comment: you said "if I re-instantiate it, then the reference no longer applies" is not exactly correct. Objects are passed by reference so if no matter what you do to that object the reference to that object will never go away as long as you never loose scope of that object.

Comment: if you do myOBJECT = new someOBJ(); 10 times in a row the myOBJECT will always refer to the same memory location that was set aside for an object of type someOBJ. so no matter what changes in that memory block it will still be typed as someOBJ and will always refer to that memory local. I don't know how else to explain it.

Comment: @The_asMan if i have myObject = new someObject, myViewStack.addChild(myObject), then myViewStack.contains(myObject) returns true. but if i do myObject = new someObject again, then myViewStack.contains(myObject) then returns false.  that is what i am encountering

Comment: What is myViewStack? If it extends another class what class does it extend? The contains function I only ever use it in 2 places. 1) To test if an object is an element of an ArrayCollection. 2) to test if it is a child display object of a parent.

Comment: Perhaps, you can post some sample code that recreates your problem so I can look at it visually.

Comment: myViewStack is the Flex ViewStack component.  So I am using the contains function to test if the display object is a child of it.

Comment: Actually I just learned something new today. The "new" operator will return a copy of the object so reference to the original object will be destroyed. In your case I would just create an INIT function to call when you want to reset the object and do the reseting in that function

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean as "reloading"? Maybe it is simpler to create data-driven components and change that data to change or reset component state>

Comment: I mean taking an already instantiated object and forcing it to go through the creation life cycle again.  I don't know if that makes sense.

Comment: I suppose it hasn't sense. You can just repopulate required data and turn your component in required state.

Comment: Well, I mainly just want to know if it's possible to do that

Comment: Yes, it is possible to create data driven component.

Answer (score 0):

Woa I'm not sure where to start here... I think THE_asMan addresses most of your misunderstandings. The missing bit I think you need to look into is how a reference to an object holds (i.e. is counted) as long as it doesn't go out of scope. Just keep in mind that as long as the a variable is not out of scope, its reference to some object (if there is one, i.e. if it is not null) is counted.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9d.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f8c